# DropDownList-Items are null on postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have DropDownList that I have to populate in an event associated with a click event of another control.. the data is populated and present but when I select a value and postback the values are null. Which means the view state is not working.. Solutions say that populate the DropDown in Init() but I can't because the requirement does not allow this. I have to populate it on click event .. Viewstates are enabled.. The following code populates the DropDown..

```
if (e.CommandName == "Add Friend")         
{
   HtmlGenericControl divMySub = (HtmlGenericControl)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("divMySubjects");
   divMySub.Style["display"] = "block";

   DropDownList mySub = (DropDownList)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("DropDownListMySubjectz");
   UpdatePanel mySubPanel = (UpdatePanel)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("UpdatePanelRequestAction");
   DataView SubjectTableView = ProfileDataAccess.GetUserUnusedSubjectsForRequest(UserId ,RequesterId).DefaultView;
   if (SubjectTableView.Count > 0)
   {
       mySub.DataSource = SubjectTableView;
       mySub.DataTextField = "Name";
       mySub.DataValueField = "Id";
       mySub.DataBind();

   } 
   else
   {
       divMySub.InnerText = "Requests Complete";
       LinkButton buttonlink= (LinkButton)sender;
       buttonlink.Enabled = false;
   }
      mySubPanel.Update();
}
```

and the following is the code for the postback that retrieves the value from the Dropdown list.. The DropDown is inside a Gridview Row.

```
protected void LinkButtonAddFriend_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Guid RequestedId = new Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
    Guid UserId = new Guid(HiddenFieldUserId.Value.ToString());
    int UserSubjectId = Convert.ToInt32 (GridViewUserSubjects.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);
    DropDownList DDL = (DropDownList)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("DropDownListMySubjectz");
    LinkButton RequestAction = (LinkButton)GridViewUserSubjects.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("LinkButtonFriendAction");
    int RequesterSubjectId = Convert.ToInt32(DDL.SelectedItem.Value);

    if (FriendsDataAccess.InsertRequest(UserId, RequestedId, UserSubjectId, RequesterSubjectId))
    {
        RequestAction.Text = "Remove Request";
        RequestAction.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

DDL is the Dropdown with trouble.

Comment: edit your title of the question - dropdown is spelled wrongly

Comment: edited can I have suggestions now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you databinding the `GridView` which is the container of the `DropDownList`? Do you have wrapped it in a `if(!IsPostBack)`-check? When you databind the `GridView` the child controls are always "resetted".

If you use a declarative databound control like `ObjectDataSource` you should avoid `this.databind()` if it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes definitely ... I have decided now never to use this.databind(). This is the second time it wasted my full week. Thanks Tim. I am  relieved so much, I can't tell.