# I have issue with viewstate of dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I try to populate the dropdown inside the gridview row on linkbutton click event. the Dropdown is populated but when I select the value and postback for later processing the DropDown appears empty .. So it means the viewstate is not written for the control.. the viewstate is enabled everywhere on page, GridView, Dropdown. and please don't tell me to populate the Dropdown in onInit because it will be totally meaningless then. Can someboady help it has been one week I just now totally helpless in this case..
this question was asked before and the link to that question is here [DropDownList-Items are null on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202717/dropdownlist-items-are-null-on-postback) the code is present there..

Comment: Is there a chance that you can provide some code + aspx markup? Especially your `Page_Load` + where you databind the `DropDownList` are of peculiar interest.

Comment: Yes I asked thsi question before and the link to that question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202717/dropdownlist-items-are-null-on-postback .. the code is present there.

Comment: When are you databinding the `GridView` which is the container of the `DropDownList`? Do you have wrapped it in a `if(!IsPostBack)`-check? When you databind the `GridView` the child controls are always "resetted".

Comment: No the gridview is populated via ObjectDataSource in markup and I used        this.databind()     in the pageload without any conditional block.

Comment: So you click a link in your grid, populate a dropdownlist and the issue is that it's empty on the next postback when you select an entry in it? Is there anything dynamically created in you page?

Comment: Thanks great.. Issue solved.. you would better make this answer so I will accept .. better post answer on the old link there it will be better to be understood..

Comment: What has solved the issue exactly?

Comment: I used this.databind() just to bind imagelink control. I removed this.databind() and solved.

Comment: Ok, i've added an answer on your other question. You might want to delete this one then.